# UIWindow does not have a member named addSubview

Tags: swift

I get an error in this line of code. UIWindow? does not have a member names addSubview. Not sure how to fix it. I am using Swift.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.addSubview(screens.to.view)
```

Comment: Unwrap the Optional. (And maybe you should stop and learn Swift before you go any further.)

Comment: Your question is a waste of bandwidth. It would be polite to delete it. In general, please try searching before you post a question.

Comment: @matt: As swift is a new language these type of questions will  help many developers to rework with the basics.So it is not a total wastage at all.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I used from a previous question to get it working properly.

```
    if let window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {

                window.addSubview(screens.to.view)}

    })
```